# Idiomatic solution to pipe if

Tags: scala, functional-programming, idioms

In our project using Scala 2.12 we have copied [the ChainingOps from Scala 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/util/ChainingOps.scala). We use it a lot and we have added one more method: `pipeIf` - when the predicate is `false`, we pass the value unchanged.

```
def pipe[B](f: A => B): B = f(self)

def pipeIf(cond: Boolean)(f: A => A): A = if (cond) f(self) else self
```

I am now experimenting porting to Scala 2.13 and this `pipeIf` concerns me a bit. All other methods in this package (`pipe` and `tap`) are already included in the Scala 2.13 library. I would prefer removing our package completely, but this `pipeIf` stays there sticking out like a sore thumb.

What is the idiomatic way to deal with "piping conditionally"?  It is not that bad, but one gripe is it prevents using underscore form. It is normal to use the verbose `if` / `else` form, or is there some other way?

```
val newState = state.pipeIf(dt != 0)(_.simulate(dt))
```

```
val newState = state.pipe(state => if (dt != 0) state.simulate(dt) else state )
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just place it in a universally available implicit class?

```
implicit class Kestrel[A](private val repr: A) {
  def pipeIf(cond: Boolean)(f: A=>A): A =
    if (cond) f(repr) else repr
  def pipeIf(cond: A=>Boolean)(f: A=>A): A =
    if (cond(repr)) f(repr) else repr
}

5.pipeIf(_ < 8)(_ * 2)  //res0: Int = 10
5.pipeIf(false)(_ * 2)  //res1: Int = 5
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I already have it placed in a universally available implicit class. I hoped I will be able to remove the whole package, as all other methods of this class are present in 2.13 std library. If there is no concise common way how is such functionality expressed, I guess the function will have to stay.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case I'd suggest just leave it as it is. Maybe it won't remain alone. You might have other ideas for should-be-in-the-library chaining methods. Then you can propose that they be added to the 3.1 release, at which time you can remove the whole package.

Comment: Shall we add `tapIf` while we are at it?

Answer (score 1):

You mention "piping conditionally". Maybe we can abstract that to "conditional function application". For lack of a better term I chose `branch`.

```scala
object Branch {
  @inline def branch[A, B](cond: A => Boolean, f: A => B, fElse: A => B)(a: A): B = if (cond(a)) f(a) else fElse(a)
  @inline def branch[A, B](cond: Boolean, f: A => B, fElse: A => B)(a: A): B = if (cond) f(a) else fElse(a)
}
```

Then you can do:

```scala
val newState = state.pipe(branch(dt != 0, _.simulate(dt), identity))
```

For `tap` I also created `branchU`:

```scala
object Branch {
  //...
  @inline def branchU[A](cond: A => Boolean, f: A => Any)(a: A): Unit = if (cond(a)) f(a) else ()
  @inline def branchU[A](cond: Boolean, f: A => Any)(a: A): Unit = if (cond) f(a) else ()
}
```

Which allows:

```scala
state.tap(branchU(dt != 0, println))
```

All of this in service of preserving access to [underscore form](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/fun-anonymous-functions.html#shortening-anonymous-functions).

Comment: Is it possible to make `identity` the default for `fElse`?

Comment: `branchU` needs a better name. Any suggestions?

Comment: hmm, `cond: Boolean` is eager above, it could be made lazy, but that could be..., for tap and pipe the lambda is evaluated immediately, but for other lambda uses... do we want the conditional evaluated at lambda creation, or at lambda invocation. `cond: A => Boolean` is lazy and is always evaluated at lambda invocation. Does Branch need both `cond: Boolean` and `cond: => Boolean`?